# O que faz a linha de código "var ? int : int"

Tags: java, android

Galera, sou novato em desenvolvimento Android e me deparei com uma linha de código assim:

`int animar =  visivel ? android.R.anim.fade_out : android.R.anim.fade_in;
        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, anim);
        animation(a);`

A minha dúvida é:
O que essa linha abaixo faz?

> visivel ? android.R.anim.fade_out : android.R.anim.fade_in

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ternario, resumidamente é um if/else compacto, caso existe um valor em `visivel`, `animar` receberá o valor após a interrogação do contrario receberá o valor depois dos dois pontos. se algo ? condição verdadeira : condição falsa.

Comment: Isso é um operador ternario, é semelhante a um if.`visivel` é a condição,  que quando verdadeira, aplica a constante inteira de `android.R.anim.fade_out ` a variavel `animar`, se for falsa, aplica a constante `android.R.anim.fade_in;` ao invés.

Comment: Seria legal outras pessoas votarem para fechar como duplicata de outras perguntas sobre o assunto, assim fica uma referência múltipla para as várias perguntas sobre o assunto.

Comment: Desculpe, mas como não estava entendo, podem abrir voto, se eu puder eu voto a favor.